# regular expression for length 6 to 20 characters with upper and lower case alphabets and numeric character support

Tags: javascript, jquery

this regex is used to test the password that support at least one lower case and upper case alphabets and numbers. this regex is not support 6 to 20 characters support.

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/

/*
 var result = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
 return result.test(value);
*/
```

Comment: `{6,20}`..........

Comment: use {6, 20} to limit the size of the password

Comment: *i want to change this regex*. Are you asking for permission? If so, go ahead. Are you asking how? Use your keyboard.

Comment: var result = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}/;
return result.test(value);

Comment: var result = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}/; return result.test(value); this supports more than 20 characters.

Comment: You shouldn't limit passwords. Please refer to [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/) for more info

Comment: ok thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Working Snippet

```js
var password = prompt("Enter password", "1234567890Aa1234567890");

var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;

console.log("Password valid?: ", regex.test(password));
```

> The regex had 2 things missing

1. The range `{6,20}`
2. Plus, the `^` and `$`, in the start and end of the regex. They signify, that the regex should apply end to end, and not a subset of the string.